# RPC-CORE: queryInfo(extrinsic: Bytes, at?: BlockHash) ... failed on weight: u64

Tags: polkadot, transactions, westend

Recently when I want to submit a transaction I receive the following failure alert, I had similar issue while getting a tx `paymentInfo`, which is resolved by upgrading apis, but while submitting a tx the alert is still come up, however the transaction will get `inBlock`.

`RPC-CORE: queryInfo(extrinsic: Bytes, at?: BlockHash): RuntimeDispatchInfo:: createType(RuntimeDispatchInfo):: Struct: failed on weight: u64:: Assertion failed`

I see the issue on Parity and OnFinality endpoints, but not on PinkNode and Dwellir !! and only on Westend and Polkadot, but not on Kusama.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the [9.2.2 release of Polkadot JS API](https://github.com/polkadot-js/api/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#922-aug-16-2022), we need to not only update all apis to the latest, but also some are replaced. in my case:

`api.rpc.payment.queryInfo`

is replaced with

`api.call.transactionPaymentApi.queryInfo`