# how to replace api.rpc.payment.queryInfo in polkadotjs now that it is deprecated?

Tags: polkadot-js, transactions, query

In https://github.com/polkadot-js/api/releases/tag/v9.8.2 api.rpc.payment.queryInfo is marked as deprecated but how can you build a transaction through polkadotjs without using it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now you have to use `state_call` with the following arguments: `["TransactionPaymentApi_query_info", <Encoded extrinsic here>]`.

This was responded in the post (both question and answer) with more detail:

- [Rpc payment_queryFeeInfo fails on Westend 9310](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/5634/rpc-payment-queryfeeinfo-fails-on-westend-9310/5648#5648).

For the new Polkadot.js API call, check the answer to this post:

- [RPC-CORE: queryInfo(extrinsic: Bytes, at?: BlockHash) ... failed on weight: u64](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/4835/rpc-core-queryinfoextrinsic-bytes-at-blockhash-failed-on-weight-u64)